# Notepad++ showing CR LF in black versus showing CR LF in blue

Tags: notepad++, html

I'm using Notepad++ as a text editor for HTML code.

Usually I see my CR-LF in black BUT occasionally I see it in blue.

What does the blue CR-LF mean?

Comment: CRLF inside a string.  So it's not a true line feed.  Mine are Purple.

Answer (score 1):

New-line that is included in a comment is displayed in a
different color.
The comment must be multi-line for this to happen.

This might be what you are seeing.